# Processing - NullPointerException converting string to float

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm working on a data visualizer so I'm bringing in data from a csv file using this code-

```
//for importing csv files into a 2d array
//by che-wei wang

String lines[] = loadStrings("food.csv");
String [][] csv;
int csvWidth=0;

//calculate max width of csv file
for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  String [] chars=split(lines[i],',');
  if (chars.length>csvWidth){
    csvWidth=chars.length;
  }
}

//create csv array based on # of rows and columns in csv file
csv = new String [lines.length][csvWidth];

//parse values into 2d array
for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  String [] temp = new String [lines.length];
  temp= split(lines[i], ',');
  for (int j=0; j < temp.length; j++){
   csv[i][j]=temp[j];
  }
}
```

That works great, but brings in all of the lines as strings. Processing has a simple float(string) conversion, but I'm getting a NullPointerException on this conversion code:

```
String[] timeString = csv[2];
float timeFloat[] = float(timeString);
```

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: So, which pointer is null??  Did you debug it to figure that out??

Comment: And where do you define `float()`?

Comment: I don't actually know how to figure out which pointer is null. I know that timeFloat is causing the issue. timeString works great, I just can't use it later in my visualization because it's a string.

Comment: And where do you define `float()`?

Comment: (If you know which statement is failing it's a simple matter to either stop on that statement with a debugger to examine the pointers being used, or use System.out.println to print the pointers, to figure out which is bad.  NullPointerException is one of the easiest to debug.)

Comment: `float timeFloat[] = float(timeString);` will not compile.  What are you REALLY doing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the 'NullPointerException' because you are not specifying what element of 'timeString' you want to store, and what element of 'timeFloat' you want to store it in. You can solve this by using a for loop. Example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < timeString.length; i++) {
        timeFloat[i] = Float.(timeString[i]);
    }
```

This for loop iterates through all values of 'timeString,' and stores them in the corresponding element of 'timeFloat'; for example, element one of 'timeString' will be stored in element one of 'timeFloat.'

Comment: When I do this it says "The local variable timeFloat may not have been initialized"

Comment: @jessemac That is because you have not initialized your array, like you have for the 'timeString' array. Example:

    float[] timeFloat  = new float[timeString.length];

Put this line before the for loop.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. I could not figure out how i was supposed to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this to convert string to float

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(timestring);
```

Comment: The parseFloat function does not work for arrays in Processing as far as I can tell from their literature, but using the float(string[]) function is supposed to work. I just keep getting a NullPointerException on the 

"float timeFloat[] = float(timeString);"

Comment: @jessemac Then check if the array `timestring` is null or not.

Comment: I guess that's the part I'm not understanding. What would make timestring null? When I comment out my conversion line and just println(timestring); there is no issue. Maybe I just dont understand what null means.